# How to close the mobile navigation menu when outside the click of menu Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to close the navigation menu when the click on outside the menu like body part how can i do that: i attach the code below

```
$(".mobile-bar-icon").click(function(){
        $(".mobile-bar-content").addClass("open");
    });
    $(".mobile-bar-close").click(function(){
        $(".mobile-bar-content").removeClass("open");
    });
```

Comment: Please share the URL so that I can check the jQuery you've written is correct or not.

Comment: Code is in my local server @Sumit

Comment: the added jQuery in the question is working fine?

Comment: I want to add when the user click on out side the menu bar, currently using above code there is one close button attach with menu bar but when i click on body it can not close

Comment: OK, let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below solution

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
     if (jQuery(event.target).is(".mobile-bar-icon")) {
         $(".mobile-bar-content").addClass("open");
     } else if(jQuery(event.target).is(".mobile-bar-close") || !$(event.target).is(".mobile-bar-content")) {
         $('.mobile-bar-content').removeClass('open');
     }
});
```

Comment: Its work for me.. Thank you @Ranganathan

Comment: Welcome...@Magento